# "Frauchiger and Renner" argument and Wigner's friend

Tags: experimental-physics

I have read some literature regarding [FR argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend#QBism) and Wigner's friend.

In short about Wigner‘s Gedankenexperiment:

> Wigner's friend is a thought experiment in theoretical quantum physics, first conceived by the physicist Eugene Wigner in 1961,[1] and developed into a thought experiment by David Deutsch in 1985.[2] The scenario involves an indirect observation of a quantum measurement: An observer W observes another observer F who performs a quantum measurement on a physical system. The two observers then formulate a statement about the physical system's state after the measurement according to the laws of quantum theory. However, in most of the interpretations of quantum theory, the resulting statements of the two observers contradict each other.

Do any one aware of any real experimental realisation(not thought experiments) of any of the two? I haven't find any.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, an 'experimental realisation' of Wigner would just involve a person who has a friend measuring the spin of a particle. I'm sure this has happened before. The point of these thought experiments is not that we expect anything exciting about their outcomes, but that they reveal difficulties in how to interpret QM.

Comment: @Pedro Treating your friend as a fully quantum mechanical object might be rather harmful for them. Just imagine evolving your friend backwards in time!

Comment: They did the experiment here my friend. https://www.science.org/doi/pdf/10.1126/sciadv.aaw9832
https://theconversation.com/quantum-physics-our-study-suggests-objective-reality-doesnt-exist-126805